# Weird tint on laptop monitor

Tags: laptop, display, dell-inspiron

I recently noticed a weird tint on my laptop's display and I can't figure out what it is or what caused it.

This is what it looks like:
[image: tint at bottom-center of display]

Does anybody know what caused this and if it can be fixed? If not, how to I stop this from happening at a greater level?

> **Info**: This display is a 4K touchscreen. It is 15.6 inch 16:9, 3840 x 2160 pixel, 10 points, LG Philips LGD04D9 / 156UD2 / Dell P/N: 53FC4, IPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is from over stressing the screen and cracking it. That’s usually from pressure applied on the outside of the lid while the laptop lid is closed and it is transported in a bag or some other means. The same thing could happen if something was closed inside the lid and it pressed on the screen as well.

Unfortunately, the screen can’t be fixed. It is also likely to get worse.

However, the screen CAN be replaced and can usually be done for a reasonable cost and is not labor intensive. But, I would recommend calling around to local repair shops if you’re not experienced with this type of repair.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I feared that something like the scenarios you described might have happened. It is most probably from "over-packing" my laptop backpack. Could you please elaborate on *"[...] It is also likely to get worse."* I was hoping to avoid a repair and just ignore this, as it is not very large or annoying. It has been there for about a week.

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich it typically will spread across a larger part of the screen. But it also might not. Only time will tell. You might get lucky. The problem is that any additional stress on the screen, like opening and closing it might make it worse.